# Installing Ubuntu on a chromebook

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Hp 14" chromebook?

It has a dual core 1.4 GHz Intel Celeron 2955U with intel graphics and 4 gb of ram.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently , yes. (*Caveat*, I have not tried this.)

1. Enter [Developer Mode](http://mikemabey.blogspot.com/2013/05/getting-into-developer-mode-on-hp.html). Any data on the HP will be deleted, and secure boot is disabled.
2. If you have not already downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop (AMD 64 bit), do so and transfer it to a USB stick. This can be done in Developer Mode as well as with another PC.
3. [Boot from the USB device and install Ubuntu.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Girn7mgoRco)
4. Update drivers for any devices that are not working. In the video above, fixing the headphone output is shown.

If anyone has done this successfully, please comment!